# Why do imports fail in setuptools entry_point scripts, but not in python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, setuptools

I have the following project structure:

```
project
|-project.py
|-__init__.py
|-setup.py
|-lib
  |-__init__.py
  |-project
    |-__init__.py
    |-tools.py
```

with `project.py`:

```
from project.lib import *

def main():
    print("main")
    tool()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = "project",
    version="1.0",
    packages = ["project", "project.lib"],
    package_dir = {"project": ".", "project.lib": 'lib/project'},
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'project = project.project:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

`tools.py`:

```
def tool():
    print("tool")
```

If I run

```
import project.lib.tools
project.lib.tools.tool()
```

it works as expected, but running the command `project` fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/project", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('project==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'project')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 568, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2720, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2380, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2386, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/project/project.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lib
```

I don't understand why the two interpreters don't have the same default import pathes.

The reason for this setup is that I want to be able to `import project.lib.tools`, but keep the directory structure with `lib/project`.

The complete `distutils` documentation seriously doesn't say a word on how one can import packages after they have been distributed (the difference of `setuptools` and `distutils` isn't less misterious - no way of knowing whether the behavior of `distutils` is extended here or not).

I'm using `setuptools` 18.4-1 with `python` 2.7 on Ubuntu 15.10.

If I change the project structure and `setup.py` as suggested in @AnttiHaapala's answer I'm getting

```
$ project
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/project", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('project==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'project')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 568, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2720, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2380, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2386, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/project/project.py", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lib
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your project structure seems to be b0rken. The standard layout for a distribution is that the `setup.py` is on the top-level. Your project would then have 1 (top-level) package, namely `project`, with sub-package `project.lib`. Thus we get the following directory layout:

```
Project-0.42/
 +- project/
 |    +- __init__.py
 |    +- lib/
 |    |   +- __init__.py
 |    |   +- tools.py
 |    +- project.py
 +- setup.py
```

Then in your `setup.py` you can simply do

```
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    ...
    # remove package_dir, it is unnecessary
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
)
```

The `package_dir` really does not handle top-level + sub-packages simultaneously very well. After that `pip remove project` so many times that you can be certain you do not have any buggy versions of it installed in the site-packages, and then run `python setup.py develop` to link the source into `site-packages`.

---

After that, the problem is that you're using Python 2 with its broken import system which assumes relative imports. In `project.py`, your `import project.lib` assumes a **relative** import by default, and it tries to actually import `project.project.lib`. As this is not what you want, you should add

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

at the top of that file. I seriously suggest that you add this (and why not also the `division` import if you're using `/` operator anywhere at all), to avoid these pitfalls and to stay Python 3 compatible.

Comment: Any idea how to make `setuptools`' `package_data` work? The problem is (basically the same) that `pkg_resources.resource_string("project", "data/file")` works in `python`, but not in the `entry_point` script.

Comment: This solution no longer works for reasons undetectable in an average human life span - or two. It seemed like python packaging isn't possible for sane people and now that it took away my sanity I'd say it isn't for anyone. What a pity...