# Module import fail, after updating command name in setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

## Originally

```
Project
|-setup.py
|-src
    |-project
        |-__init__.py
        |-cli.py
```

```py
...

entry_points="""\ 
[console_scripts] 
cli.py = project.cli:main 
""",
...
```

The only change I have made to the code was I updated the console scripts. I renamed cli.py command to project_cli.py, since making this change the I have been receiving a *Traceback* error as shown below.

#### Changed

```py
...

entry_points="""\ 
[console_scripts] 
project_cli.py = project.cli:main 
""",
...
```

#### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./project_cli.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Project==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'project_cli.py')()
  File "/Users/myusername/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 487, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Users/myusername/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2728, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/Users/myusername/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2346, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/Users/myusername/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2352, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named project.cli
```

Similar question [Why do imports fail in setuptools entry_point scripts, but not in python interpreter? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803310/why-do-imports-fail-in-setuptools-entry-point-scripts-but-not-in-python-interpr) <= this did not resolve my issue.

I tried updating the path so that instead of `project.cli:main` it was `src.project.cli:main` but this still **failed**
I tried renaming the file `cli.py` to `project_cli`  but this still **failed**

```
Project
|-setup.py
|-src
    |-project
        |-__init__.py
        |-project_cli.py
```

```py
...

entry_points="""\ 
[console_scripts] 
project_cli.py = project.project_cli:main 
""",
...
```

Any help to resolve this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you changed `cli.py = project.cli:main` to `project_cli.py = project.project_cli:main` and renamed `cli.py` to `project_cli.py`?

Comment: By the way, you should use Python 3. Python 2 is no longer supported, see https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

Comment: I still received a `ImportError: No module name project.project_cli`
While I know Python 2 is no longer supported, that is not something I can change at the moment.

Comment: I believe this should work. Maybe the issue is somewhere else. One thing that might help is to reinstall the project. By the way what command did yo use to install it? What does the following command return: `python3 -c 'from project.cli import main; main()'`?